# Translating JSON to a different JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have a requirement to translate a JSON from One schema to another.

The JSON comes from a C# application, and I am not allowed to modify from there.

From the C# application, the JSON is stored to a nvarchar field in particular table.

The source coming from C# is formatted as follows:

```
{
    "officeSummary" : {
        "name" : "Test Office",
        "geographicData" : [{
                "addressLine1" : "AddressLine 1",
                "city" : "TestCity",
                "stateProvince" : "NJ",
                "postalCode" : "08543"
            }
        ],                  
    }
}
```

I need to translate it to this:

```
{
    "office" : {
        "name" : "Test Office",
        "officeAddress" : [{
                "streetAddress" : "AddressLine 1",
                "city" : "TestCity",
                "stateProvince" : "NJ",
                "postalCode" : "08543"
            }
        ],                  
    }
}
```

Is there any way we can translate this by change the key names using the SQL Server JSON functionalities? Like `JSON_VALUE` or `JSON_MODIFY`

Comment: what produces the JSON Schema/file? is it a Stored proc?

Comment: Its stored as nvarchar in the database table.

Comment: What stores the JSON to your database table? Basically I'm trying to pinpoint where we will modify.

Comment: the database gets value from c# application. The source json is the one that gets stored to the database and the destination is the one that i would need to retrieve from the database.  I am not in a position to update the json from the C# code. That is the reason why i am trying to do it with SQL. I am okay to do the modification before saving to the table or while fetching from Database

Comment: Do you want to change the JSON *stored on your database* or *when it is queried from the database*?

Comment: Either of the option will work for me

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [Example - Rename a key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql#examples), you can use a 3-step process to rename a key. Below I have provided the code for renaming 'addressLine1' to 'streetAddress'.The same method can be used to replace the remaining values, although it becomes a bit messy. Notice, renamed key is moved to the end, but this should of course not affect json-parsing applications.

```
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
    "officeSummary" : {
        "name" : "Test Office",
        "geographicData" : [{
                "addressLine1" : "AddressLine 1",
                "city" : "TestCity",
                "stateProvince" : "NJ",
                "postalCode" : "08543"
            }
        ]                  
    }
}'

SELECT @json =
JSON_MODIFY(
    JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.officeSummary.geographicData[0].streetAddress'
        , JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.officeSummary.geographicData[0].addressLine1')
    )
, '$.officeSummary.geographicData[0].addressLine1', NULL)

PRINT @json
```

Result

```
{
    "officeSummary" : {
        "name" : "Test Office",
        "geographicData" : [{

                "city" : "TestCity",
                "stateProvince" : "NJ",
                "postalCode" : "08543"
            ,"streetAddress":"AddressLine 1"}
        ]                  
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need to look at the [Example - Modify a JSON object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql#examples) too, in using `JSON_QUERY` to avoid double escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [modify json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) .net libraries functionality from Newtonsoft combined with a SSIS script transformation task (assuming you have SSIS available).

Then you could read the property value into a variable. Delete the property and create a renamed property with the saved value.